# Overriding Third-Party Metadata - JMSSerializerBundle and FOSUserbundle

Tags: php, symfony

I have an issue with JMSSerializerBundle and my override entity of FOSUserbundle.

I use JMSSerializerBundle to serialize my entities and FosRestBundle to make an API. There is no problem with my own entities but when i tried to serialize my user entity overriden from FosUserBundle It does not work the way I want.

I would like to expose only the username from User entity given by FOSUserbundle and also show some properties of my own entity (overridden).

When I set into config file this configuration, the YML file is ignored.

```
jms_serializer:
    metadata:
        auto_detection: true
        directories:
            - { path: @bwbUserBundle/Resources/config/serializer, namespace_prefix: 'FOS\UserBundle' }
```

I also tried this synthaxe :

```
jms_serializer:
    metadata:
        auto_detection: true
        directories:
            FOSUserBundle:
                namespace_prefix: FOS\UserBundle
                path: "@bwbUserBundle/Resources/config/serializer"
```

There is my `Model.User.yml` contained into `@bwbUserBundle/Resources/config/serializer` directory

```
FOS\UserBundle\Model\User:
    exclusion_policy: ALL
    # add your desired configuration below.
```

When I use FosRestBundle to return User object. It returns all entity properties.

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "username": "******",
  "username_canonical": "******",
  "email": "******@******",
  "email_canonical": "******@******",
  "enabled": true,
  "salt": "******",
  "password": "******",
  "last_login": "******",
  "locked": false,
  "expired": false,
  "roles": [
    "******",
    "******",
    "******",
    "******",
    "******",
    "******",
    "******"
  ],
  "credentials_expired": false
}
```

Thanks for your help.

My apologize for my English I try to be better :)

Answer (score 0):

Tested on Symfony 4. Try creating a `Entity.User.yml` in `/config/serializer/Entity.User.yml` with the following contents:

```
App\Entity\User:
    exclusion_policy: ALL
    properties:
        id:
            expose: true
        username:
            expose: true
```